# Setting UIImage scale doesn't work as expected in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, scale

I'm setting the UIImageView's frame, but setting the UIImage with a scale amount doesn't seem to have any effect on the image's size. Only the the UIImageView's width and height changes the size:

```
    chooseStillImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgViewWidth, height: imgViewHeight))

    chooseStillImageView?.image = UIImage(cgImage: photo.cgImage!, scale: 0.75, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)
```

Changing 0.75 doesn't change the size. I tried putting it in a main dispatch  with no difference. Maybe I just don't understand what scale is supposed to do, but according to the documents:

> The scale factor to assume when interpreting the image data. Applying a scale factor of 1.0 results in an image whose size matches the pixel-based dimensions of the image. Applying a different scale factor changes the size of the image as reported by the size property.

printing the chooseStillImageView?.image.size does indeed have a width and height.

Comment: Changing the image size won't change the way UIImageView display your image. You need to change the `contentMode`

Comment: I tried setting the UIImageView's contentMode to both scaleAspectFit and scaleAspectFill after setting the image with a scale. Still no difference.

Comment: Do you have an example where setting up my UIImage's scale and contentMode makes the scale work? I can't find anything that works.

Comment: So if you have a `UIImageView` of 100x100 and you put a 50x50 image inside it and you use `.aspectFit` or `.aspectFill` or `.scaleToFill`, it will display a 100x100 image because it will fit perfectly in the view. If you use almost any other content mode (e.g. `.center`) you'll see that the `scale` makes a difference.

Comment: What you can also do, after setting the `.image` property, is call `chooseStillImageView?.sizeToFit()`, which should make the size of the frame match the image.

Comment: Ah okay. What was strange about this is setting the scale argument didn't have any effect. The image is something that appears on the screen for only a fraction of a second, and maybe that's why because setting the scale that way isn't fast enough? Anyway, I use CGAffineTransform to set the scale, and it seems to work.